# An algebra isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, algebras

Considering $\mathbb{C}$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, it is easy to find a vector space isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$. I am struggling to justify why $f:\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$, determined by the following:
\begin{equation}
1\otimes1\mapsto(1,1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1\otimes i\mapsto(i,-i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
i\otimes1\mapsto(i,i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
i\otimes i\mapsto(-1,1)
\end{equation}

determines an algebra isomorphism. My notes say that 'the multiplication table of $\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is preserved', but I'm not really sure what this means. I'm aware that there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362365/algebra-isomorphism-mathbbc-otimes-mathbbc-to-mathbbc2), but the answer given uses methods beyond my level, and I guess my question is more specific to the above mapping. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to multiply elements of $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: So for example would you have $(1\otimes{i})(1\otimes{i})=(1)(1)\otimes(i)(i)=1\otimes{-1}$? But then $(i,-i)(i,-i)=(ii,(-i)(-i))=(-1,-1)$, so I don't see the correspondence here.

Comment: @JohnMartin : I don't, how do we define the multiplication for making $A \otimes A$ an algebra in general ? do we consider the algebra of linear operators over $A$ ?

Comment: Yes. See @jl2's comment. I was running into the same problem.

Comment: @jl2 $f(1\otimes -1)=f((-1)(1\otimes 1))=-f(1\otimes 1)=-(1,1)=(-1,-1)$.

Comment: @Slade thank you, of course I need to be applying $f$ to see the correspondence.

Comment: @Slade Oh. Right. That was a dumb mistake on my part...